# Group summary hiding and changing the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
$("tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass('myAltRowClass');

var i, groups = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "groupingView").groups,
    l = groups.length,
    idSelectorPrefix  = "#" + this.id + "ghead_2_";

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (groups[i].cnt === 1) {
            $(idSelectorPrefix + i).hide();
        }
    }

    //var gd=jQuery("#master")[0];
    //gd.grid.footers
    //      alert("YES");
    //});



//var element = $('#master>tbody>tr>td>div');
//element.each(function (i) {
//  alert(i);
//    $(this).closest('div').find(".RCSummaryFooter1").text("check");
//});
```

},

```
   /*-----------this is from jqgird----  */  
   tr class="ui-widget-content jqfoot ui-row-ltr" role="row" jqfootlevel="1">
   <tr id="masterghead_1_3" class="ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-ltr masterghead_1"  role="row">
   <tr id="masterghead_2_4" class="ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-ltr masterghead_2"  role="row" style="display: none;"> 
   <tr class="ui-widget-content jqfoot ui-row-ltr" role="row" jqfootlevel="2">
      <td aria-describedby="master_HD" style="">
          <div class="RCSummaryFooter1">Total </div>
       </td>
```

Dear sir,
I am hiding the second level group text if only one record existed. this is from the ID (masterghead_2_4) I need to hide the summary as well. How could I access the tr since there is no Id for this tr (jqfootlevel="2") I have three groupings. This is the second level which I need to hide. I need to change the text of the summary as well. At the moment it is displaying word "Total" for all three summary levels. I need to change the text as 'Accounts Total', Activity total and Cost/Rvnu Total respectively. Thanks in Advance. 
Please understand it is because of this site only I was managed to do all these work I have done so far. I am a Informix guy and new to this subject. If any one have ideas please share it

Answer (score 0):

I managed solve the issue. But if some one has better way of doing please let me know.
The first issue was to hide the group headings and summary totals if the count ==1. 
I need to hide two groups if in the event count ==1

```
     loadComplete: function() {     
          /* --Hiding cost/revenue and Activity summary Values  ---*/
         $('tbody tr').each(function(n,opts) {
          if(opts.getAttribute('jqfootlevel')=='2' && opts.cells[2].innerText ==1){
             opts.style.display='none';
          }
          if(opts.getAttribute('jqfootlevel')=='1' && opts.cells[2].innerText ==1){
             opts.style.display='none';
          }
       });
```

jqfootlevel is one of the attributes representing summary value tr (no id is available in this tr)

The following code segment I copied from **Mr. Oleg's answer**. This is to hide the Group header. In this case I am hiding only one Group header. (group 2- Cost/Rvnue Group)
/* --This is hiding Cost/Revenue Group header if total =1 --*/

```
    var i, groups = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "groupingView").groups,
    l = groups.length,
    idSelectorPrefix     = "#" + this.id + "ghead_2_";
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (groups[i].cnt === 1) {
            $(idSelectorPrefix + i).hide();
        }
    }
```

Following code will change the Total word as given below. So that it will display as 
Cst/Rvnu Total
Activity Total
Accounts Total

```
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      var element = $('tr[jqfootlevel='+i+']');
      switch(i){
        case 0:
           var txt="Accounts Total";
           break;
         case 1:
           var txt="Activity Total";
           break;
          case 2:
            var txt="Cst/Rvnu Total";
            break;
       }
       element.each(function (n,opts) {
        opts.cells[0].innerHTML=txt;
        opts.cells[0].style.color='tomato';
        if(i<2){
           opts.cells[2].innerHTML="";
        }

   });
```